# Which device to use to measure AC current using Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, current

I'm building a home automation product and want to measure AC current using Arduino (as of now). I've used ACS712 5A Hall Effect Current module but there's a lot of electrical noise and also the accuracy is not good. There's a lot of deflection in value when no current passes through it. I want to pack the whole kit in a box. So how to make sure that there will be no magnetic interference?

Can you suggest some other module to use for the same? Also that can last long enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sort of Current Transformer usually does the trick.  You run the AC line (not the neutral) through a ferrite core and it converts current into an output voltage.  You can find them packaged like [this one](http://www.dx.com/p/yqj010504-single-phase-ac-current-sensor-module-w-active-output-deep-blue-5a-294209#.Vd20A_lVhBc) with a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ac%20current%20sensor).